Combining outer product of two lists
I have two lists,
 mylist1 = {{a, 1, 2}, {b, -3, 5}};
 mylist2 = {{c, -1, 6}, {d, -4, 7}};

I would like to make the outer product of these two lists, then combine the elements of the outer product such as the first elements are multiplied together, while the other two elements are added together. The following function does this:
 Flatten[Outer[{#1[[1]] #2[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]], #1[[3]] + #2[[3]]} &, mylist1, mylist2, 1], 1]

but  am wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way to do this? I played around a bit with MapThread in the same style as in the answers to this question, but could not quite make it to work?

You asked for efficient or elegant. Efficient is heavily influenced by context. You would most likely need to test different approaches to find the most efficient. As for elegant, that's largely a matter of taste. An argument can be made that point-free style is higher on the elegance scale:
Outer[
  CurryApplied[MapApply[Construct]@*Thread@*List, 3][{Times, Plus, Plus}], 
  mylist1, 
  mylist2, 
  1] // Catenate

On the other hand, you might find it more elegant to just show the semantics explicitly:
myFunc[{a1_, a2_, a3_}, {b1_, b2_, b3_}] := {a1 b1, a2 + b2, a3 + b3};
Outer[myFunc, mylist1, mylist2, 1] // Catenate

Alternatively, you might use more of a workflow approach. First create the structure, and then apply the desired combining functions:
MapAt[Apply[Plus], {All, {2, 3}}]@
  MapAt[Apply[Times], {All, 1}]@
    Transpose[Tuples[{mylist1, mylist2}], {1, 3, 2}]


Clear["Global`*"];
mylist1 = {{a, 1, 2}, {b, -3, 5}};
mylist2 = {{c, -1, 6}, {d, -4, 7}};

g = MapThread[#1[#2] &, {{Apply[Times], Total, Total}, 
    Transpose[{#1, #2}]}] &

Catenate@Outer[g, mylist1, mylist2, 1]



{{a c, 0, 8}, {a d, -3, 9}, {b c, -4, 11}, {b d, -7, 12}}


A bit of a hack, but for such kind of input works
Join @@ Outer[Plus, mylist1, mylist2, 1] /. Plus -> Times

